# Should you thank comment answers to your comment questions with a comment or just up vote?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, thanks

I understand that [a separate thanks isn't useful for answers to your questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-thanking-users-who-answered-my-question), but in comments, you're often asking a specific question of one particular person (as opposed to anyone who reads your question and has time / inclination / ability to answer), so it seems that a thanks is more in order.

I could just up vote the comment, but how would the commenter know that it was I who upvoted the comment and not someone else?

It seems more human to leave a comment, but it seems better for keeping the noise to content ratio low to merely up vote the answer comment.

What are your views on this? Not leaving a final, `Thanks!` comment just seems so cold.... even though, leaving it definitely increases the noise to content ratio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Thanks!" is too short anyway; you'll have to add *something* else to get past the comment length checking, so why not make it something *meaningful*?

Suggestions:

- Thanks! That worked great!
- Thanks! That didn't work at all, but it did help me recognize an unrelated mistake that was causing the problem.
- Thanks! I'm still lost - how do you make a function in C again?
- Thanks! Your solution blew up my house and killed my dog. I don't recommend anyone else trying it.
- Thanks! Your last comment was directly responsible for the destruction of The Universe. I never liked it anyway.
- Thanks! I was afraid I would have to ask a separate question, but thanks to you the solution to my second problem is now locked away in a hard-to-find comment thread!

Comment: |||||> `@blah - What does "rm -rf /" do in your script file?` |||||>
`@peter - Nothing. It's a comment.`   
|||||> `@blah - Thanks! I really want to thank you in person. What's your address?`