# Change minimum comment length to 10?

Tags: feature-request, comments, character-limit

Sometimes all I want to say is `Thank you.`, but I need '5' more letters 'to go'. I've seen people write *"4more"* or *"kdjgodfjg"* or other things to get around this. Can we short the comment minimum to be 10 so we don't have to do this to simply say thank you?

Comment: "Thank you" is only 8 non-whitespace characters anyway.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59278/should-you-thank-comment-answers-to-your-comment-questions-with-a-comment-or-just

Comment: :p but seriously, I second @Shog9's [answer there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59278/should-you-thank-comment-answers-to-your-comment-questions-with-a-comment-or-just/59284#59284). Accepting an answer and upvoting means "thank you" anyway. Plus you can add a bounty if you want

Comment: I Googled *kdjgodfjg* thinking it was some sort of leetspeak or code, only to find it is pure gibberish. Such a disappointment :(