# Is it important to say "thanks" after getting correct answer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)

I want to know that if got the correct answer and I accepted the answer. Then is it necessary that I have write some lines like thanks or fixed my issue as comment. Will it be considered rude from the person who gave the answer.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/

Comment: At the end of the day, we're ingrained and we thank each other a lot. It's hard to change that. And sometimes it feels rude not to thank people who do extra. Thank You!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. In fact, because it just noise to the page without adding any information, saying "thanks" is discouraged (though tolerated).

Instead, it's preferred that askers thank answerers by accepting and/or upvoting the answers.

Comment: I would think it would be more reasonable and not so much noise if the poster was to put thanks in the original post at the very bottom.  (If they just must say thanks)

Comment: @DougChamberlain: I prefer the use of comments, because they can be cleaned up later without bumping the post. When I feel really compelled I'll say "Thanks", leave the comment for a couple of hours so the person can see it, then delete it. The sentiment gets across, but there's no cruft left on the page.

Comment: Do points get rewarded for saying thanks?

Comment: @RobSandie: No.