# Why is saying "Thank you!" in question undesirable

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
>   [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)
>   [Is it important to say “thanks” after getting correct answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109956/is-it-important-to-say-thanks-after-getting-correct-answer)

My question was edited by respectable Stack Overflow member. Only thing that was changed - removed "Thank you!" at the bottom of question.

Is there any particular reason why should I not say that?

Comment: It's unfortunate if that was the _only_ edit, it seems like needless noise to me. But if there's something else in the question that could be improved, removing the thanks and greetings and so on makes enough sense.

Comment: Why would additional edits be a requirement?

Answer (score 24):

Think of your question (and it's answers) as a mini blog post.  The goal of writing a blog post is (or should be) to provide useful information to others with a minimum of noise and clutter.

Would you say "Thank You!" in your blog?  What for?

Instead of saying "Thanks," upvote the answers that helped you, and accept the answer that helped you the most.

Better yet, pay it forward by answering the questions of others.

Comment: Good catch. On the other hand: Isn't it a kind of respect people pay when they say "thank you"? In a logical view you're 100% right, but we are humans. And yes: sometimes I say "thanks" under a blog post. For what? The author gets confirmation and keeps up writing.

Comment: Come on! So we should say very bad things to everyone who ask a very basic question without researching the web because it shouldn't happen again. You should agree that this kind of things more undesirable than saying hello. But we can't, we are humans. Maybe in the near future, chat bots can do this. And then we will need these human things more.

Comment: I disagree that "thank you" should be discouraged or removed.  If I wrote a blog post asking for feedback or ideas on a solution to a problem, I might say "thank you for your help."  I think that if a user wants to include "thank you" in their post, they should be allowed to, and it should not be edited away.  I think allowing this sign of gratitude contributes to a positive community attitude.