# 'answer?' In search preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ios-app

I found out a strange bug while searching for some possible duplicates in the search field.

When seeing it in the search field, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115694/275420)'s preview becomes

> answer?

while there is a lot of content inside the question.

[image: !]

[image: !]

Why is this happening? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug. But actually you can see "answer?" in "Is it important to say “thanks” after getting correct answer?"

Comment: @nicael Whoops, didn't spot that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The raw HTML we get back from the server looks like this:

> ```
>  answer?  
>
>
>
>
>  My question was edited by respectable Stack Overflow member. Only thing that was changed - removed &quot;<span class="highlight">Thank</span> <span class="highlight">you</span>!&quot; at the bottom of question.
>
>  Is there any particular reason why should I not <span class="highlight">say</span> that?
>   &hellip; 
>    Possible Duplicate:
>    Should &#39;Hi&#39;, &#39;thanks,&#39; taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?
>    Thanking users who answered my question
>    Is it important to <span class="highlight">say</span> “thanks” after getting correct &hellip;
> ```

And we had some logic that said unescape the characters, replace the `<span ...` with bold text, and show the first 5 lines.  In this case four of those lines were blank.

The correct way to do it, so that it matches the web is to actually render the HTML and then display the first 5 lines.  This treats those four blank lines as a single space.