# How can I show my appreciation for someone's time taken to answer my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)

Everyone likes to be appreciated, especially when they take time out of their day to help someone just because they're passionate about what they do and are a bit altruistic.

However, whenever I say thank you on StackOverflow, generally my thanks or salutations are edited out leaving just the question. Which is fine... I mean, it makes my question more concise, but I feel rude not to acknowledge the help I'm being given (other than providing an upvote).

Is it really a case of "there's no need to thank us"? I do try to contribute answers wherever I can, but I feel the balance is always shifted more to me asking questions than providing answers - which is a shame.

What's the proper etiquette in this community?

Comment: Now that I've answered and am looking for links to make my answer more useful, I've stumbled across [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question), which may answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

Signing posts, along with thanks/salutations, are not necessary parts of a question. The question should cover the issue, without extra content to clutter it.

The four primary ways to thank a user for providing an answer are

- Upvote the answer. The user gets +10 rep, and everyone sees an increased vote count on the answer
- [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/167443) (one accepted answer per question). The answerer gets +15 rep, and the community sees that answer as the solution to the issue addressed in the question
- [Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/167443) on the answer (explain what helped, what didn't, why it was great, etc). No rep gain for anyone, but a personalized message everyone can see
- Award a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/167443). This will cost you some of your rep (between 50 and 500), and it will be awarded to whomever you select as the winner. Nice prize, plus a marker indicating which answer received the award.

Remember, other people may have your issue later, and searching the internet (or StackOverflow) will lead them to your question (and its answers). Therefore it's the actual question content that matters, not the pleasantries/signatures attached to it.