# Community Owned Posts

Tags: support, community-user, ownership

I am curious to know about the community owned posts.

Is there a place where we can see the total number of community owned posts: both questions and answers, sorted by users who first posted them?

Who is the user whose posts have been owned by the community user the most?

Comment: So is your question "please write the SEDE query to get this info I asked about", or are you interested in the ownership of Wiki posts?

Comment: I had a preconceived idea that community wiki would generally own posts that are like the basic faq. Stuff that people using SE need to know. So I was interested in knowing who helped to build the community. That's why I asked for statistics.

Comment: But now that Monica Cellio pointed that there is no consensus about community wiki, I would like to know both

Comment: I also don't understand what is there to downvote in a question about statistics. Does the downvote means the question is not valid? Or does it mean it is not useful? (Maybe to them! ha!) I am wondering if curiosity will kill the cat?!??

Comment: I have rolled back your edits that changed the question out from under an existing answer.  If you want to use what you learned here to ask a *new* question feel free to do that.

Comment: I think you have been confused by a very old information. The part you quoted was written six years ago when things were very different. Since then I'm 99.999% sure CW posts no longer owned by the Community account.

Comment: Ok, can someone edit that wrong info?

Comment: Thanks for all the people who have been very very patient with me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer was posted in response to revision 1 of the question, which was later changed.**

I think you're confusing two concepts here.

*Community wiki* is the process of opening a post (question or answer) for community editing.  Because they're designed to be collaborative, they stop earning reputation from the time they are given this status.  *However*, those posts are still owned by whoever posted the first revision; the posts are linked on that user's profile, and that user will earn badges for votes, views, favoriting, and so on.  Those posts are *community wiki* but not *community-owned*.

The other way that one might think posts would become community-owned is if an account is deleted (or a post is disassociated).  But those posts aren't transferred to the Community user; they simply become ownerless.  You can spot these because the user names (which may be something like "user1234" or "anon") are not links to user profiles.  Other "things" associated with users, like flags and votes, can sometimes be transferred to the Community user, but posts are not.

I don't know of a way to search for community-wiki posts from the on-site search and sort by original author (owner), but you might be able to do it through [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).  According to the schema, the Posts table has a column for CommunityOwnedDate, which might be the date the post became community wiki (if it is).  There's a separate column for OwnerUserId, so you could write SQL to do what you want if you're ok with operating on data that's not completely current.

Comment: Hi @MonicaCellio the post here suggested otherwise to me. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: Please clarify further, the post says transfer of ownership

Comment: I think that phrasing there is a little off.  Look, for example, at [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140578/162102).  It's community wiki, as you can see in the "answered by" block at the bottom, so I don't get rep from it.  But it's linked on my profile, and when it reached a score of 10 I got a Nice Answer badge.  So it's still "my" answer in those ways, but it's also community wiki, meaning it's easier for other people to edit it (like a wiki).  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you, can you make an edit on the referred question to reflect this?

Comment: I will check SEDE. Thanks

Comment: Is the question ok now?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a programmer and so don't know how I can create a query like that, I'll see if someone takes pity on me and does that for me

Comment: you have to either edit your answer or the community wiki to clear up the misunderstanding properly. What you have posted makes sense. But the wiki quoted above directly refutes what you say. Please clarify.

Comment: No I don't *have to* do either of those; you changed the question after I posted this answer and all I "have" to do is to roll back your subsequent edits to the question.  I only held back on that to give you the chance to fix it yourself.  If you have a new question (or complaint about that page) you can ask it separately.  If you want to edit the other post you can do that.  I answered your question and cleared up your misunderstanding, and this is how you respond?  That's not cool.

Comment: That was not my intension or my tone. I was asking in a friendly manner only. Also I edited the question to correctly reflect what I wanted to ask, as I am a new user. Forgive me if I offended you. I asked to correct the site about community user because I still don't know enough to make the correct edit

Comment: Ok thanks.  This was starting to look like a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/162102).  It's probably best to just ask a new question about that meta post if the word "owned" there is tripping you up.

Comment: Lol, Oh my! It sounds exactly like this post. I asked you to correct it to prevent other new users like me from asking the wrong question. I guess the correct etiquette would be to accept the answer and post another question, though I doubt it will be closed as a duplicate!!!

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me. I will ask a new question. Is it ok to quote what you have written vs what was there in that OLD OLD wiki post?

Comment: Sure, quoting & linking from one question to another is fine, even encouraged (saves people having to look for context).