# Showcase of Stack Overflow-contributed projects and/or methods to show appreciation?

Tags: discussion

I am currently developing a web application that is far above my knowledge level, but thanks to the help, input and contributions of the Stack Overflow community, the learning and development process has been nothing more than a breeze.

This isn't just [thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question), but moreso indebting myself and my project to the Stack Overflow community.

It would be nice if Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange hosted an area wherein users could upload images and/or include links to the programs they have developed using the support of the Stack Exchange community — a 'showcase' if you will.

If this type of idea is inappropriate for or misaligned with Stack Exchange's goals, then how many of you would be interested a 3rd-party website that could showcase these SO projects? Just a place where you could say, "Hey, here's what I built — thanks Stack Overflow!"

Comment: You can add a link to those projects in your profile.

Comment: This would be somewhat self defeating. It would be better for us to receive links that cite our awesomeness from those that achieved awesomeness, no? If you really want to go out of your way to say thanks, just do so on your product's web site.