# Feature Request: Implement bitcoin tipping

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to implement bitcoin tipping, so that you can give a microtip to your favorite answer?  Changetip.com has already implemented microtipping on github, reddit, and other sites.

Besides upvoting, this would be a nice way to thank someone for spending the time to write a good answer and would encourage more high quality results.

Comment: -1, I don't think this will be very useful, or at all in line with how SE works. I've seen some people's profiles on different sites that have a Bitcoin address -- you can microtip that way, if you really want to.

Comment: @Servy I don't think so, though these questions are certainly *related*.

Comment: @Servy there's exact cross-site duplicate at MSO: [Integrate cryptocurrency tipping](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281232/839601)

Comment: gnat I'm going to delete this question as it is an exact duplicate. ERM it wont let me delete it as its a duplicate from another site..

Comment: @SameerAlibhai you can't delete as there is an upvoted answer.

Comment: Wow so much downvotes for seemingly very useful feature. I'd love to see function that allows me to leave tips on helpful answers (just I'd prefer it in form of regular currencies).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to give a "thank you" for a post, you can upvote their post.

If you want to do something *more* to thank an especially useful answer, you can [pay it forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17878/266359) by answering another question. That's all you need to do.

If you really feel like you want to tip someone in Bitcoin, check a user's profile -- some of them have Bitcoin addresses in there. I'm pretty sure those users wouldn't say "no" to a tip :)

Comment: Great idea!  Maybe then it would work well as a tip feature on the user profile page?

Comment: @SameerAlibhai: people that are open to tips already have it listed in their About Me. We don't need any specific feature to facilitate that.