# Criteria for deleting comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, moderators

What is the criteria for deleting comments? Why isn't there a notification that a comment was deleted? Just today, I gave a big thank you to a contributor (Ed Beal) whom I respect a lot for supporting my answer, calling it 100% code compliant. Then when I looked again at my post my thank you comment was GONE!  I realize the actual questions and answers have a more strict protocol, but I thought comments would be more casual and not subject nearly as much scrutiny. Certainly not to the extent of deleting them with no notice or explanation... this needs to change. BTW, it was on the DIY portion of SE.

Comment: Different communities have different standards for how comments are handled. This is probably better directed to the [DIY Community](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're looking for a _specific_ answer to why that type of comment was removed. If you're trying for a genuine [feature-request] on MSE to add a notification for comment deletion then that would need much more supporting details as to why we would benefit from something like that and why developers should spend the time to implement it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: The above linked FAQ explains the guidelines for commenting, specifically that comments containing only comments or criticisms that don't add any new information are not allowed, and that any comment that violates the guidelines is subject to deletion.

Comment: That could be a case for "spring-loaded" comments: Ephemeral comments which are deleted after a set time, say 72 hours. (As a trade off, they would be protected from most deletions (only by moderator intervention).) There could be restrictions on who could post them.

Answer (score 10):

When adding a comment, there's a visible placeholder text:

[image: placeholder text when adding comment]

And in words:

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information.

It's there for a reason, to explain what you *should* write as a comment. Anything else would be candidate for deletion, without any notice.

Back to your case: a comment to thank someone, no matter who it is or what they did, is **not** asking for clarification and it does not adding any information. Hence, it's expected such comments would be deleted.

I believe your core problem is confusing Stack Exchange with social networks, where comments are important part, perhaps the most important part, of the network. Stack Exchange is platform for Questions and Answers, where the focus is the content, not the people and neither the comments made on the content.

Also, note there's whole faq for how to properly thank people who posted content you find useful: [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)

Comment: The tooltip for "Add a comment" also makes it clear: *Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. **Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".***

Comment: @Justin interesting, I see [tooltip which is the same as the placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JODZu.png). Where exactly you see such tooltip? Might be a userscript.

Comment: I didn't see it before, but *Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"* is only shown in the placeholder text (and the tooltip) when adding a comment on **answers**.

Comment: @Justin neat, there are actually even more, the placeholder for *own answer* is different. Three different variations.

Answer (score -2):

One common criteria for flagging a comment for deletion is:

> - **It's no longer needed.**
>   This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.

This is because long strings of conversation, or comments like "Thanks a bunch!" are rarely useful to other people reading the post later down the line.

Presumably the comment was flagged as such and consequently deleted (possibly by the person you were thanking, after they read it).  In your particular case deleting this comment perhaps seems a bit harsh.

And I agree that a notification for when a comment is deleted would be nice, but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: *"In your particular case deleting this comment seems a bit harsh."* - thank-you comments are unnecessary noise, their deletion is not personal, so calling it "harsh" appears to miss the point of everything quoted prior. *"And I agree that a notification for when a comment is deleted would be nice."* - the number of comments whose deletion is either unremarkable or should definitively be unremarked, far exceeds the number where notification might somehow be useful - but even then the usefulness is minimal, since if you needed notification to know it's gone, did you really even care it exists?

Comment: I don't know anything about SE:DIY, but "100% code compliant" seems like it is saying more than just "thanks" - hence _somewhat harsh_

Comment: Saying "100% code compliant" and "thanks" were two different comments by two different people. In fact, neither are retainable as comments on an answer, since showing support and approval is done by voting and bounties; if it was necessary to demonstrate an answer's compliance with the relevant building code, that information should be included in the answer as well.